# Regex not working with accented characters in Datatables plugin

Tags: jquery, regex, search, datatables

I'm trying to implement Datatables search with regex.

It works fine if I search for "lu..a" (returns Lucia, Luzia, LUZIA, etc), but not works if I try for "concei..o" (looking for Conceição, conceicao, etc).

The problem is with accented characters such "ç" or "ã" (pt_BR) in database.

I already try the accent-neutralise plugin, but it makes the inverse effect  (https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/type-based/accent-neutralise)

In the table initialization there is a lot of options that I'm omitting here (buttons, translate, etc), but one important detail is this tablet is retrieving data from server-side.

Here is the search code:

Source: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

```js
// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$('.exportTable tfoot th.select-filter').each(function() {
  var title = $(this).text();
  $(this).html('<div class="form-group form-float" style="width: 100%">' +
    '<div class="form-line">' +
    '<input class="form-control" placeholder="' + title + '" title="Filtrar ' + title + '" type="text" style="width: 100%">' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>');
});

table = $('.exportTable').DataTable();

// Apply the search
table.columns().every(function() {
  var that = this;
  $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
    if (that.search() !== this.value) {
      that
        .search(this.value, true, false, true)
        .draw();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? Working here: https://plnkr.co/edit/AQsAqOY1biByRz1AwBVi?p=preview

Comment: I just figure out that not works only when is server-side processing. I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need a more complete table of [**diacritics**](http://web.archive.org/web/20120918093154/http://lehelk.com/2011/05/06/script-to-remove-diacritics). I do not claim the mentioned table is complete, but far the best I know. Include the script and

```
jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string = function (s) {
    return removeDiacritics(s)
};
```

demo with *Conceição* -> **https://jsfiddle.net/s2yo99de/**

---

**Update**: The above solution is now included as part of the official DataTables plugins

Sorting -> **https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/diacritics-sort**
Filtering -> **https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/type-based/diacritics-neutralise**

Comment: I tried your answer and it worked fine on client side processing. My table is retrieving data from server and on this case it not works.
Sorry not mentioning it before. I didn't know if is a different case.
Do you know what is needed on this case?

Comment: @MarceloBarros,  ?? There is nothing that indicates that you are using serverside processing.  Please show  exactly how you initialize the dataTable and which type of serverside script you are using (guess you are using a standard script, it differs among different serverside platforms)

Comment: Here is the full code: https://gist.github.com/marcelobdsilva/1a092089043acca4a6059f5bddc4c5e1

Comment: @MarceloBarros, ok, but it was the serverside script `/api/customers-data` that is interesting :) this is where you need to get rid of those diacritics.  I can only guess what you are doing and which platform you are on, but somewhere in the script you retrieve rows based on the passed criterias, in mysql you would force ignoring accented chars by `...where table like '%xyz%' collate utf8_general_ci` ...If you use mysql, try add `collate utf8_general_ci` to the statements.

Comment: Understood. I'm working with Laravel PHP framework and Yajra's Datatables package on backend, so if I try to explain all this in the question, it can be very confuse. But I got the reference now and will try to implement it in backend. The diacritics is the right answer. Thanks a lot!